# how to get the common items count of lists

Tags: python, algorithm

there is a dictionary containning many lists, for example,

```
  list_dic= {
    q1:[1,2,3,4,5]
    q2:[2,3,5]
    q3:[2,5]
    }
```

and I want to get all common items count for each list, e.g. the common items count for q1 and q2 is 3=(2,3,5)

```
q1={q2:3, q3:2}
q2={q1:3,q3:2}
q3={q1:2, q2:2}
```

my code for this task is:

```
result = {}
for name, source_list in list_dic.items():
    for target_name, target_list in list_dic.items():
        count = 0
        for item in source_list:
            if item in target_list:
                count+=1
    result[name][target_name] = count
```

but this algorithm is inefficient, I want to know a better algorithm to do this task

Comment: does your lists contain unique numbers or not? if they do, how common items are counted in that case?

Comment: @VB9-UANIC: lists are compared in pairs. If two lists contained unique numbers (across both lists), the count of common numbers (common to both lists) would be zero, would it not? What's your point?

Comment: my point not about uniq numbers across lists. is this ok or not?

list_dic= {
      q1:[1,2,2,2,2]
      q2:[2,3,5]
      q3:[5,5]
    }

Comment: i answered as if it's a bad case and shouldn't happen

Comment: FWIW -- I think that algorithm description could use a little help here, but it's definitely not a bad question.  The problem is described and code is provided which makes a good attempt at solving the problem.  The biggest place that people have to complain about this one is that it is possibly better suited for `codereview.stackexchange` since OP claims the code already works.  Anyway, +1 on the question from me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
import itertools
import collections

q1 = 'q1'
q2 = 'q2'
q3 = 'q3'

dic_list = {
     q1:[1,2,3,4,5],
     q2:[2,3,5],
     q3:[2,5]
     }

#sets are much more efficient for this sort of thing.  Create a dict
#of the same structure as the old one, only with `set` as values 
#instead of `list`
dic_set = {k:set(v) for k,v in dic_list.items()}

new_dic = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for k1,k2 in itertools.combinations(dic_set,2):
     #to get the count, we just need to know the size of the intersection
     #of the 2 sets.
     value = len(dic_set[k1] & dic_set[k2]) 
     new_dic[k1][k2] = value
     new_dic[k2][k1] = value

print (new_dic)
```

If you're following the comments, it turns out that `combinations` is slightly faster than `permutations`:

```
import itertools
import collections

q1 = 'q1'
q2 = 'q2'
q3 = 'q3'


dic_list = {
     q1:[1,2,3,4,5],
     q2:[2,3,5],
     q3:[2,5]
     }

dic_set = {k:set(v) for k,v in dic_list.items()}

def combo_solution():
     new_dic = collections.defaultdict(dict)
     for k1,k2 in itertools.combinations(dic_set,2):
          value = len(dic_set[k1] & dic_set[k2])
          new_dic[k1][k2] = value
          new_dic[k1][k2] = value
     return new_dic

def perm_solution():
     new_dic = collections.defaultdict(dict)
     for k1, k2 in itertools.permutations(dic_set,2):
          new_dic[k1][k2] = len(dic_set[k1] & dic_set[k2])
     return new_dic

import timeit
print timeit.timeit('combo_solution()','from __main__ import combo_solution',number=100000)
print timeit.timeit('perm_solution()','from __main__ import perm_solution',number=100000)
```

with the results:

```
0.58366894722    #combinations
0.832300901413   #permutations
```

This is because `set.intersection` is an O(min(N,M)) operation -- Which is cheap, but can add up if you're doing it twice as many times as you need to.

Comment: +1: Another way of looking into this problem, instead of using permutation. I think both the solution is equally efficient, but that needs to be timed.

Comment: yeah, +1 for equally neat solution.

Comment: @Abhijit -- I think my answer will be faster as it calculates half as many intersections -- Calculating the intersection for sets is an order N operation, so it's not something that you can consider to be completely free.  Of course, there's also the question of whether `combinations` is less efficient than `permutations for some reason, but I doubt it.  Anyway, I'll benchmark and post the results.

Comment: @Abhijit -- timings posted.  Feel free to point out anywhere that I might have done it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
#Create a default dict. You don;t have to handle KeyError condition
result = defaultdict(dict)
list_dic= {
    'q1':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'q2':[2,3,5],
    'q3':[2,5],
    }
#Convert the value list to set list
set_dict = {k:set(v) for k,v in list_dic.items()}
# For both way mapping, you need permutation i.e. (q1, q2) and (q2, q1)
for k1, k2 in permutations(set_dict.keys(),2):
    # Now `&` is Set Intersection. The Len will return the length of the common elements
    result[k1][k2] = len(set_dict[k1] & set_dict[k2])


result
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'q1': {'q3': 2, 'q2': 3}, 'q3': {'q1': 2, 'q2': 2}, 'q2': {'q1': 3, 'q3': 2}})
```

Comment: @mgilson: I was updating my solution before you commented. Yes combination is more efficient but per OPs question, I think permutation is what we would need here

Comment: you can simplify "for k1,k2 in list(permutations(list_dic.keys(),2)):" to "for k1,k2 in permutations(list_dic,2):"... easier to read.

Comment: @isedev: Its a reminiscent of my debugged version :-)

Comment: anyway, +1... neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't bother if lists can contain duplicate numbers, you can do it with the set() type

```
>>> s1 = set([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> s2 = set([3,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> s1 & s2
{3, 4, 5}
```